# SQL how to select participant IDs with specific row values in same table, where those row values are from a lookup list in another schema?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I want to select participants from a table that have both the diagnoses Cancer and Diabetes in Column B

For example:

```
ParticipantID Diagnosis
1234          Cancer 
1234          Diabetes
4567          Cancer
4567          Lung Disease
8910          Stroke
1256          Lung Disease
3489          Chron's Disease
```

How do I write a query that allows me to select participants that have two (or more) of a certain diagnoses, for example I only want to see participants that have both Cancer and Diabetes? (in the above example, participant ID 1234)

I tried doing a simple select statement:

```
SELECT diagnosisifknown.participantid
diagnosisifknown.diagnsis
diagnosisifknown.date
FROM
diagnosisifknown
where diagnosis ="1" and "10";
```

(the values for these diagnoses in the lookup table)

I want an output like this:

```
1234   Cancer
1234   Diabetes
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation provides one simple option:

```
SELECT ParticipantID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ParticipantID
HAVING MIN(Diagnosis) <> MAX(Diagnosis);
```

You could also use exists logic here:

```
SELECT t1.ParticipantID
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.ParticipantID = t1.ParticipantID AND t2.Diagnosis <> t1.Diagnosis);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with cte and here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fmj1K7P3SkiFZDeFgQSdAa/0).

```
with cte as
(
  select
    ParticipantID
  from myTable
  where Diagnosis in ('Cancer', 'Diabetes')
  group by
      ParticipantID
  having count(ParticipantID) > 1
)

select
    c.ParticipantID,
    m.Diagnosis
from cte c
join myTable m
on c.ParticipantID = m.ParticipantID
```

output:

```
| participantid | diagnosis |
| ------------- | --------- |
| 1234          | Cancer    |
| 1234          | Diabetes  |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want *participants*, you can use:

```
SELECT d.participantid
FROM diagnosisifknown d
WHERE diagnosis IN ('Cancer', 'Diabetes')
GROUP BY d.participantid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

If you want the original rows, I might suggest `EXISTS`:

```
select d.*
from diagnosisifknown d
where exists (select 1
              from diagnosisifknown d2
              where d2.participantid = d.participantid and d2.diagnosis = 'Cancer'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from diagnosisifknown d2
              where d2.participantid = d.participantid and d2.diagnosis = 'Diabetes'
             ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies! In my database, the values for these diagnoses seem to be from a lookup list, with the values I want to see being assigned '1' and '10'. When I try to run your second query, I get the error "argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer", and when I try inputting the text diagnoses I want back 'cancer' or 'diabetes' I get the error say it's not recognized. Any way around this?

Comment: @Syd . . . This answer uses the data values and column names as specified in your description of the question.